# Microsoft Excel - Find all occuring combinations of 5 characters out of a list of 6 characters separated by commas

Tags: excel

I have a list of items of 6 characters each. For example, all 6 character combinations of alphabets a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h as below.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,g
a,b,c,d,e,h
a,b,c,d,f,g
a,b,c,d,f,h
a,b,c,d,g,h
a,b,c,e,f,g
a,b,c,e,f,h
a,b,c,e,g,h
a,b,c,f,g,h
a,b,d,e,f,g
a,b,d,e,f,h
a,b,d,e,g,h
a,b,d,f,g,h
a,b,e,f,g,h
a,c,d,e,f,g
a,c,d,e,f,h
a,c,d,e,g,h
a,c,d,f,g,h
a,c,e,f,g,h
a,d,e,f,g,h
b,c,d,e,f,g
b,c,d,e,f,h
b,c,d,e,g,h
b,c,d,f,g,h
b,c,e,f,g,h
b,d,e,f,g,h
c,d,e,f,g,h
```

Now, I have a sample of 5 characters out of the same characters. For example 'a,c,f,g,h'. I want to be able to find all rows that this combination occurs in, and highlight them with a different font/fill colour. In the above example, rows 10,19 & 20 must be highlighted as the 'a,c,f,g,h' combination occurs in them.

is this possible in Microsoft excel? If yes, how. If not, is there another option? Thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: Use a conditional formatting rule based on a formula using SEARCH, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As per your provided example give a try on below conditional formatting formula-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"b,",""),"d,",""),"e,","")="a,c,f,g,h"
```

[image]